# Process LaTeX code only if package is loaded

Tags: packages

I would like to create a document used to test diverse packages, and I was wondering if it was possible to use a command so that part of the code is read only if the corresponding package is loaded. I've come up with this but it throws an error which I don't know how to fix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPackageLoaded}[3]{\@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\IfPackageLoaded{natbib}{natbib loaded}{natbib not loaded}
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \IfPackageLoaded{natbib}{natbib loaded}
                                            {natbib not loaded}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

I also know that the command `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` exists when loading the package `ltxcmds` but when I try to use it in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\begin{document}
\ltx@ifpackageloaded{natbib}{natbib loaded}{natbib not loaded}
\end{document}
```

I get this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \ltx
         @ifpackageloaded{natbib}{natbib loaded}{natbib not loaded}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Can someone please point out what I did wrong?

EDIT: changed `documentclass` from `minimal` to `article`.

Comment: You are missing the `\makeatletter` in your second example. And don't use the minimal class, normally it is too minimal.

Comment: Read more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/156344

Comment: It is said in the [`ltxcmds` documentation](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/ltxcmds.pdf#subsubsection.1.13.2) that `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` can be used after `\begin{document}` though.

Comment: But even then it can only be used if you wrap it in `\makeatletter...\makeatother` because it has an `@` in its name.

Comment: Oooh, that's why! I'll try then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following commands were [added](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/621) to LaTeX in the November 2021 release, so you no longer need to define your own.

`\IfPackageLoadedTF`, `\IfPackageLoadedWithOptionsTF`, `\IfClassLoadedTF`, `\IfClassLoadedWithOptionsTF`

```
\IfPackageLoadedTF{package name}{true code}{false code}
```

Answer (score 6):

As users Ulrike Fischer and moewe pointed out, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPackageLoaded}[3]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\IfPackageLoaded{natbib}{natbib loaded}{natbib not loaded}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: The `[3]` is not needed. You can simply use `\newcommand*{\IfPackageLoaded}{\ltx@ifpackageloaded}`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke RIght; also `\let\IfPackageLoaded\ltx@ifpackageloaded`

Comment: @egreg Yes, because `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` is a *simple* macro. If it would be, e.g., robust, it could be better to use `\LetLtxMacro` from package `letltxmacro`. I didn't want to explain all this, so I've only noted about using `\newcommand*` without arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution by @Lashoun is probably most robust,
I was curious if we can achieve the same thing without loading `ltxcmds`.

Reading the guts of `ltxcmds.sty` and `latex.ltx`,
it seems that loading a package (specifically, the `\ProvidesPackage` command)
defines a macro `ver@{packagename}`.
So, we can check whether this is defined as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % toggle me!
\newcommand{\ifloaded}[3]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname ver@#1\endcsname\relax%
    #3\else#2\fi}
\begin{document}
  \ifloaded{hyperref.sty}{yes}{no}
\end{document}
```

I'd be interested in experts' thoughts on the limitations of this simple solution.
I simplified much of the code from `\ltx@ifundefined` from `ltxcmds`,
but maybe I simplified too much!
Also, this seems to work without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` ... but does it really?