# Trick with lineno on both sides can't be "compiled-out" via ltxcmds

Tags: conditionals, renewcommand, lineno

Some time ago I took the solution from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199593/87996) to show `lineno`'s line numbers on both sides of the page.

However, I want numbers to be in place only sometimes (say when I need to send the document to somebody else for corrections), so I want to be able to remove `lineno` in a consistent way by just commenting its `\usepackage` line. For this purpose, I searched an found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484092/87996), and thought I could use it to compile-out both the linked trick and the `\linenumbers` command.

Unfortunately, it looks like the `\OnlyIfPackageLoaded` command defined below can't compile-out the trick I mentioned earlier, because the `\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{ the trick I mentioned above }` causes a compilation error (on the other hand, the line `\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{\linenumbers}` seems to be doing what I expected).

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left, pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\OnlyIfPackageLoaded}[2]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}
\makeatother

\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{
\makeatletter
\def\makeLineNumberLeft{%
  \linenumberfont\llap{\hb@xt@\linenumberwidth{\LineNumber\hss}\hskip\linenumbersep}% left line number
  \hskip\columnwidth% skip over column of text
  \rlap{\hskip\linenumbersep\hb@xt@\linenumberwidth{\hss\LineNumber}}\hss}% right line number
\leftlinenumbers% Re-issue [left] option
\makeatother
}

\begin{document}

\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{\linenumbers}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

---

I've tried using the answer proposed at [the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201348/why-doesnt-makeatletter-work-inside-newcommand) but I haven't managed to make it work.

Since `\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{\linenumbers}` does what I expect, I assume that

```tex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\OnlyIfPackageLoaded}[2]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}
\makeatother
```

is correct and needs no change. So what needs change is

```tex
\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{
\makeatletter
\def\makeLineNumberLeft{%
  \linenumberfont\llap{\hb@xt@\linenumberwidth{\LineNumber\hss}\hskip\linenumbersep}% left line number
  \hskip\columnwidth% skip over column of text
  \rlap{\hskip\linenumbersep\hb@xt@\linenumberwidth{\hss\LineNumber}}\hss}% right line number
\leftlinenumbers% Re-issue [left] option
\makeatother
}
```

but how? I've tried removing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and then changing `\hb@xt@` to `\csname hb@xt@\endcsname`, <s>but I get the same error.</s> Nevermind, I must have made a typo on the first attempt.

Comment: (different specific command, same issue, same fix applies.)

Comment: Why not just use a custom `\if`. You can keep the package and just place the relevant macros inside `\if...` wrappers, then you can use `\...true`/`\...false` as a switch. But indeed correctly positioning `makeatletter` and `\makeatother` already should solve your problem.

Comment: @user202729, I don't think I've understood how to use that solution. I'll add my attempt to the question.

Comment: You should not write `\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{ \makeatletter` ... `\makeatother }`, but `\makeatletter \OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{` ... `} \makeatother`. So, you should place `\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{` ... `}` *between* `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, because these two macros may not be used inside other macros.