# Commenting out lineno and disabling commands related to it via ltxcmds fails to compile unless I manually delete the aux file

Tags: conditionals, lineno

From [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678276/trick-with-lineno-on-both-sides-cant-be-compiled-out-via-ltxcmds?noredirect=1#comment1683531_678276), take this example

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left, pagewise]{lineno} % LINE
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\OnlyIfPackageLoaded}[2]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{
\def\makeLineNumberLeft{%
  \linenumberfont\llap{\hb@xt@\linenumberwidth{\LineNumber\hss}\hskip\linenumbersep}% left line number
  \hskip\columnwidth% skip over column of text
  \rlap{\hskip\linenumbersep\hb@xt@\linenumberwidth{\hss\LineNumber}}\hss}% right line number
\leftlinenumbers% Re-issue [left] option
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\OnlyIfPackageLoaded{lineno}{\linenumbers}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

where `\OnlyIfPackageLoaded` is used to make `lineno`-related things disappear if I comment out its `\usepackage`.

Unfortunately:

- if I compile from a clean directory with `THAT` line commented, the compilation succeeds;
- if I decomment `THAT` line and recompile, the compilation succeeds;
- if I re-comment `THAT` line and recompile, the compilation fails:

  ```
  ...
  (./main.aux
  ! Undefined control sequence.
  l.2 \@LN
          {0}{0}
  ?
  ```
- if I delete the `.aux` file and recompile, the compilation succeeds.

What can I do to avoid having to manually delete the AUX file when I go from with-`lineno` to without-`lineno`?

Comment: it is very common that removing a package makes it necessary to delete the `.aux` . `hyperref`, `longtable`, ....

Comment: but you could  `\def\@LN#1#2{}` in your no-package code

Comment: why `ltxcmds` rather than just use the standard latex `\@ifpackageloaded` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to not hide the else branch of `\@ifpackageloaded` so you can define the aux command to do nothing. (`ltxcmds` does nothing here as this is all already latex)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left, pagewise]{lineno} % LINE
% not useful here \usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\OnlyIfPackageLoadedTF}{\@ifpackageloaded}
\newcommand{\OnlyIfPackageLoadedT}[2]{\@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\OnlyIfPackageLoadedTF{lineno}{
\def\makeLineNumberLeft{%
  \linenumberfont\llap{\hb@xt@\linenumberwidth{\LineNumber\hss}\hskip\linenumbersep}% left line number
  \hskip\columnwidth% skip over column of text
  \rlap{\hskip\linenumbersep\hb@xt@\linenumberwidth{\hss\LineNumber}}\hss}% right line number
\leftlinenumbers% Re-issue [left] option
}
% else
{
\def\@LN#1#2{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\OnlyIfPackageLoadedT{lineno}{\linenumbers}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\def\@LN#1#2{}` for? And what are `T` and `TF` suffixes meant to stand for?

Comment: @Enlico as you show in your question the aux file has lines `\@LN{...}{...}` and you need to define them to do nothing. TF is a convention used by several newer latex commands mimicking expl3, the  TF version has true and false arguments the T version is your original with just a true branch and no else